# autofit image when browser window resize

Tags: html, css, image, resize, scrollbar

i want that my image size doesnt change when my browser window resize and it should cover all the div content ..
the problem is when i resize my window background image only cover showed browser area and its look like my content is out of its div..its okey if there is scollbar..but doesnt able to find solution even with that..plz help..

here goes my code...

```
<style>
div{
 background-width:100%; 
 background-image: url('back5.jpg');
 background-id:back5;
 background-overflow-x:scroll;
}

</style>

</head>

<body style="margin:0px;overflow-x:scroll">

    <div>

    <img src="logo.gif">





    <label  style="type=text/css;position:absolute;left:600px;top:18px"/>

            <font size="5" style="color:#ffffff">E-mail:</font>

    </label>

    <label  style="type=text/css;float:right;position:absolute;left:600px;top:48px"/>

            <font size="5" style="color:#ffffff">Password:</font>

    </label>

    <Input type="text" name="_email" id="e_mail"  style= " type=text/css;-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
                                                          -moz-border-radius: 7px; border-radius: 7px;
                                                           background-color:#D8D8D8;
                                                           float:center;position:absolute;
                                                           left:720px;top:18px;
                                                           width:400px; height:25px"/>

    <Input type="text" name="_password" id="pass_word"  style="type=text/css;-webkit-border-radius: 7px; -moz-border-radius: 7px;
                                                                border-radius: 7px; background-color:#D8D8D8;
                                                                float:center;position:absolute;
                                                                left:720px ;top:48px; width:400px;
                                                                height:25px"/>

    <input type="submit" value="LogIn" style="type=text/css; float:center;position:absolute;
                                             left:870px ;width:600px; top:80px; width:60px;
                                             height:25px"/> 

    </div>



</body>
```

Comment: Just as a tip, clean up your code. Drop the style attribute on the HTML tags and move all styling to your <style> tag at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use bootstrap responsive class for images,

[get bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive) and include bootstrap.css to your code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

then you can use

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you can try a well known CSS3 property called background-size.

```
background-size: 100%;
```

This will only work in modern browsers. More info can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size

Comment: it doesnt work dear... run my code then u "ll understand my problem

Comment: What browser are you using?